# Getting raw pcm audio buffer from XAudio2 when playing compressed file

Tags: xaudio2

Is this possible to access the raw audio `PCM` data that is being played when using `XAudio2` to play file?

I've been searching for several ways to access a decoded version of audio files being played in SL4/Windows Phone, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post someone had success writing a custom XAPO that just grabs samples and is enabled on a Submix Voice. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/05593fad-dfd8-4c77-983b-8c84cd4a324b/xaudio2-saving-output-custom-xapos-slow-down-audio-play-backwards

Please note that if you just want to do this for audio processing this approach is not optimal because you are limited to the speed of audio playback.

Comment: Can't wait to test it. For now, I've made a Windows Phone runtime component that eats user's MP4 and spits the raw pcm. It's running at 8 times the original MP4.